# Yahrtzeit in Second Adar according to Rav Moshe?

Tags: yahrtzeit, adar

The below article references a teshuva from Rav Moshe regarding the second Adar being the primary Adar as far as yahrtzeits. The listed source of Y.D. Vol. 3 160.1 is actually regarding hilchos ribbis. Anyone can advise as to an updated accurate source?

https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed in [Yoreh De'ah 3:160:1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&pgnum=430) (found in vol. 6 of Iggerot Moshe).